# Creating a model and linking an existing model by id with a nested serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Can I use a nested serializer to link an object created by the parent serializer, to an existing model?

I have 2 simple models, Client and Account. Let's say they both have just an id, and a name, the Account also has a (not null) foreign key to the Client.  I create 2 serializers, and I nest the ClientSerializer in the AccountSerializer, as I want to see data about the Client when looking at the Account.

```
class ClientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
    class Meta: 
        model = Client 
        fields = '__all__'


class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
    client = ClientSerializer(required=False)
    class Meta: 
        model = Account 
        fields = '__all__'
```

This works fine for reads, but if I wanted to POST to create an account, can I do this with the AccountSerializer as it stands? Trying the following:

```
serializer = AccountSerializer(data={
    "client_id": 1,
    "name": "new account" 
})
```

I get the error `{'client': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')]}`, even though the nested ClientSerializer is `required=False`.  If I try this:

```
serializer = AccountSerializer(data={
    "client": {"id": 1},  # Client of id 1 already exists
    "name": "new account" 
})
```

Then I'll get `{'client': {'name': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')]}}`, even though I wouldn't want to create a Client nor edit the client's name.

I just want to create an Account, and link it to an existing Client (of id=1), in a generic, reusable way.  Is this something possible with DRF without having to define custom logic in a `create` method?

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is change the `to_internal_value` method of the `ClientSerializer`. Something like:

```py
class ClientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
    class Meta: 
        model = Client 
        fields = '__all__'

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        if isinstance(data, Client):
            return data
        elif isinstance(data, int):
            return get_object_or_404(Client, pk=data)
        elif isinstance(data, dict) and data.get('id'):
            try:
                return get_object_or_404(Client, pk=int(data.get('id')))
            except ValueError:
                pass
        raise serializers.ValidationError('Client should be an integer or client item formatted object')
```